# SWAGGER UI retorna el objeto pero no las listas relacionadas

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un server WebApi con 2 clases:
class **Marca**
Campo1

class **Camion**
Campo1
Campo2
Campo3
List Marcas

y un Controlador **CAMIONES**
[HttpGet]
public Get(Camion  varCamion)

Desde la **interface de SwaggerUI**, en el GET del controlador CAMIONES puedo cargar Campo1,2y3 y puedo cargar el array de Marcas.

El Controlador **recibe en el Get** el objeto Camion en **varCamion**, pero el Count de Marcas en 0, es decir ***no impactan las marcas cargadas en array***.

Uso NetCore 2.2,  c#  y Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.1.4

Agradezco mucho si me pueden ayudar.
saludos!!!

> `curl -X GET "https://daniels:500/api/CAMIONES?Campo1=valor1111&Campo2=2222&Campo3=3333&Marcas=%7B%0A%20%20%22campo1%22%3A%20%22Toyota%22%0A%7D" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImM4OWRmM2M2ZWFhN2UwZWViOTNlNjk3YTFmODgyYjk5IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MjI3NDIxODEsImV4cCI6MTYyNTMzNDE4MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kYW5pZWxzOjUwMCIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL2RhbmllbHM6NTAwL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImFwaTEiXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiQkFTQ1MiLCJzdWIiOiIyMTJjNzhlNy04YmQ3LTQ4MGYtOWFjZi1iNTNkZTUzNGQyMzEiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MjI3NDIxODAsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwiTm9tYnJlIjoiZHNhbHVtIiwiRGlzcGxheU5hbWUiOiJEYW5pZWwgU2FsdW0iLCJHdWlkIjoiMjEyYzc4ZTctOGJkNy00ODBmLTlhY2YtYjUzZGU1MzRkMjMxIiwic2NvcGUiOlsib3BlbmlkIiwicGVyZmlsIiwiYXBpMSJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.s7T1Dz3VOYhQxGEc2gmqJreBKgjpJdtqHuSe8xP4eLZgba8eMTqd2fFPoW5xtiXHi116YbhQ448DhosrZHNDX4G4zjE9OqQhNPIyZE4pSNen4SZ7ndLIf2MK7hbxlJMJ0Nlt5ySWE00-hQFSmVXpNe68eaKmVFltjl2HvNS1ptxnHY726l-ZKIDhTQIZfNWSus4DucX5m0sxTLMwGVMy5drw91kulDV9AWb26EFfJyRD7ASEcJu7LbtUChgNf2cAp5zpY4fUjx6GV5a836j1UfxmFYf8ymVldiV2vO1VBw0I8bTRXqRS1bmfV7X06NovyLNqOZwdVQD2iOTwVLasJA"`

```
RequestURL
https://daniels:500/api/CAMIONES?Campo1=valor1111&Campo2=2222&Campo3=3333&Marcas=%7B%0A%20%20%22campo1%22%3A%20%22Toyota%22%0A%7D
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: puedes poner el json que te devuelve, y el json que esperas? y la relacion de lo que te devuelve a lo que quieres recibir